Bad file when setting map_yaml_file in launch file, but not when passing in via CLI
I am trying to pass a file into the map_server node from nav2_map_server for navigation. When I set up a launch file to do it like this:
map_yaml_file = LaunchConfiguration('map')
map_yaml_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    'map',
    default_value=os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('my_package_name'), 'maps/limo', 'my_map_name.yaml'),
    description='Full path to the map yaml file to load')

localization_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
    os.path.join(nav2_bringup_dir, 'launch/localization_launch.py')),
launch_arguments={'map': map_yaml_file}.items())


ld = LaunchDescription()
ld.add_action(map_yaml_file_cmd)
ld.add_action(localization_cmd)

I get the following error messages from map_server:
[map_server-6] [ERROR] [map_io]: Failed processing YAML file 
~/ros_ws/src/my_package/maps/limo/my_map.yaml at position 
(-1:-1) for reason: bad file: 
/full/path/ros_ws/src/aws_robomaker_bookstore_world/maps/limo/bookstore.yaml
[map_server-6] [ERROR] [1733500989.791187317] [map_server]: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[map_server-6] [ERROR] [1733500989.791212418] [map_server]: Original error: Failed to load map yaml file: ~/ros_ws/src/my_package/maps/limo/my_map.yaml

However, when I pass the map in via CLI like in the following:
ros2 launch my_package my_launch_file.launch.py  map:=/full/path/ros_ws/install/my_package/share/my_package/maps/limo/my_map.yaml

It works fine.
Is my setup for the launch file incorrect? I did notice that if I use the ~ character for the map arg in CLI, it won't find the file - I have to use the global path. And in the error output from when I don't pass it in via CLI, it shows the ~ character AND the full path.
For reference, my yaml file is below. It was generated automatically so I don't think there's a formatting error.
image: bookstore_map.pgm
mode: trinary
resolution: 0.05
origin: [-7.72, -7.54, 0]
negate: 0
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.25

If you have any insight or answers, then please let me know.

Is the error not about the file '/full/path/ros_ws/src/aws_robomaker_bookstore_world/maps/limo/bookstore.yaml' and not about the file '~/ros_ws/src/my_package/maps/limo/my_map.yaml'?  Just my 2 cents
